# How to setup a java 11 based spring boot pipeline on bitbucket?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-11, bitbucket-pipelines

Build fails with "invalid target release: 11" message.

After a commit to bitbucket, a pipeline job starts automaticly but fails with

```
Full Error Message:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project sms-commons: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 ->
```

How to enable java 11 support?

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
          - mvn clean install
```

I expect a successfull build, but as I wrote the build job fails.

Comment: Which java version have you defined in pom.xml? <java.version>X.X</java.version>

Comment: In my POM I defined java 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of the maven Compiler Plugin

org.apache.maven.plugins
    maven-compiler-plugin
    3.8.0

And you need a maven Docker image that is providing java 11 for example maven:3-jdk-11

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the image to image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-11  and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

I use: `ehsaniara/bitbucket-util` as [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/ehsaniara/bitbucket-util).

example:

```
options:
  docker: true
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Production Build on Master
          image: ehsaniara/bitbucket-util:latest
          trigger: automatic
          script:
            - mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need maven image which supports jdk 11, so update your "image" value like below:

```
image: maven:3.8.3-jdk-11

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
          - mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

Find at docker the maven image that fits to maven and jdk version. Also select the publisher of JDK you want
For maven 3.9 and JDK 17, I found: maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine